# Not able to invoke locally AWS Lambda using Serverless

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a problem and maybe someone can help me.
I'm trying to build a simple java aws lambda and deploy it using serverless framework.

I've tried to build a simple lambda using:

```
sls create --template aws-java-maven --name test-lambda
mvn clean install package
sls deploy
```

When I try to invoke the remote function using

```
sls invoke --function hello -d '{}'
```

it works.

But when I try to invoke it locally, I have the following error:

```
Serverless: Building Java bridge, first invocation might take a bit longer.
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn mvn ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (it worksinternal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

EDIT:
To run it locally I use:

```
sls invoke local -f hello
```

I've googled it and I found nothing. I don't understand the error.
It looks like something about maven?

Comment: Did you use serverless offline plugin

Comment: No? I did not use it

Comment: how did you run lambda in local ?

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Maven or ensure that 'mvn' is on your PATH.

For me on Mac 'brew install maven' did the trick.